# From where do the initial values of the variable length array (VLA) in [c] come?

Tags: c, variable-length-array

example c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char** args) {

    int k = 8;
    int sendbuffer[k]; // VLA

    for (int n = 0; n < k; n++) {
        printf("sendbuffer[%i]: %i \n", n, sendbuffer[n]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
sendbuffer[0]: 1 
sendbuffer[1]: 0 
sendbuffer[2]: 1583871280 
sendbuffer[3]: 32767 
sendbuffer[4]: 22544384 
sendbuffer[5]: 1 
sendbuffer[6]: 1713234504 
sendbuffer[7]: 32767
```

**From where do the numbers in `sendbuffer[]` come from?** And why are sendbuffer[2,4,6] the only ones that change when running the code again?

I'm using clang compiler on OSX El Capitan (compiling with `gcc example.c`)
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix

If is a different behavior with other compiler/OS, I'd like to hear about these cases too.

Comment: Undefined behavior. The values are whatever happens to be in the memory.

Comment: This is not specific to VLAs.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't just for VLAs; the behavior above is for any variable declaration. If you declare a variable, for example

```
int a;
```

This allocates `sizeof(int)` bytes on the stack, at whichever address the system chooses. The memory there is *uninitalized*; it is whatever happens to be there at the time. It is up to the programmer to initialize the memory.

Answer (score 3):

[Online C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.7.9/10: "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate..."

Unless you declare it at file scope or with the `static` keyword<sup>1</sup>, a variable won't be initialized to any specific value; the contents will be whatever was last written to that memory location.

---

1. Neither of which apply to VLAs; they cannot be declared `static` or at file scope, nor can they have an explicit initializer.

Answer (score 1):

These values are called *garbage values*, they're whatever that was in memory when the array was created interpreted as `int`s.

Your program just says to the OS: "gimme that part of memory pls" and so the OS does, giving it to your program *without changing the contents*.